# object detection api is not working with colab

Tags: object-detection-api

!apt-get install protobuf-compiler
!cd Tensorflow/models/research && protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. && cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py . && python -m pip install .
----------------this part code is not running in colab.----------------
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

%%bash
cd models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install

------------------error-----------------------
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

### note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('bash', '', 'cd models/research/\nprotoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.\ncp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .\npython -m pip install .\n')

i tried object detection . that part of code is not running .. is it a problem with colab or some other issues?